# How to retrieve individual element from the list in the protractor test script

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I Just want use jasmine-data-provider in my protractor test script.
Test case : in the angular page there are 4 anchor tag elements i want to compare those anchor tag text's using protractor.

my PO file is as below

```
   dashboardAllelements(){
        return element.all(by.className('module hero'));
   }
```

my spec is as below

```
using(dashBoardTestData.dashBoardData , function(testData){
        it('to check the dashboard hero names before edit', ()=>{          
          var i=0;
          page.dashboardLinkClickEvent();
          var array = page.dashboardAllelements();

           expect(page.dashboardAllelements().getText()).toEqual(testData.heroName);
           browser.sleep(1000);
          });
    })
```

My test data file is as below.

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
    dashBoardData : [
        {heroName : 'Narco'},
        {heroName : 'Bombasto'},
        {heroName : 'Celeritas'},
        {heroName : 'Magneta'}
    ]
}
```

My test case result is below.

```
Expected [ 'Narco', 'Bombasto', 'Celeritas', 'Magneta' ] to equal 'Narco'
Expected [ 'Narco', 'Bombasto', 'Celeritas', 'Magneta' ] to equal 'Bombasto'
Expected [ 'Narco', 'Bombasto', 'Celeritas', 'Magneta' ] to equal 'Celeritas'
Expected [ 'Narco', 'Bombasto', 'Celeritas', 'Magneta' ] to equal 'Magneta'
```

can any one help me what's my mistake is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **toEqual()** to **toContain()**

```
expect(page.dashboardAllelements().getText()).toContain(testData.heroName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . test case is passed now